# How can I make a .click file from an installed app?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

I have installed an app and I want to make a .click file of it. In the future I could install it locally.
Sometimes I do not want the following versions of an application and prefer an earlier one.

Comment: What is `.click`?

Comment: It's a file that allows install an app locally. It has the .click extension

Answer (score 1):

If you like the version of an app you can create a `.click` file before updating it.
The installed apps are inside directories in `/opt/click.ubuntu.com`.
You go there with `File Manager` and copy the dir of the app you are interested on.
In the directory `~` you have the script `reb_click.sh`
Write to the Terminal:
`./reb_click.sh  "PASTE_FROM_FILE_MANAGER"`
You paste the address with File Manager.
It has a complete direction but the script cleans it.
After that you get a directory of the app in `~`
Inside it is the `.click` file you where looking for.
The script `reb_click.sh` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
paquete=`echo ${1##*/}`
cp -r /opt/click.ubuntu.com/$paquete ~
cd ~/$paquete/current
cp .click/info/$paquete.manifest manifest.json
cd ..
click build current
```

To install the app put the `.click` file in `~` and write to the terminal:
`pkcon install-local name_of_the_app.click --allow-untrusted`
It just won't be signed with the official appstore key like the one that can be downloaded from the store.
See the Niklas Wenzel page:
http://nikwen.github.io/ubuntu/2016/02/05/rebuilding-a-click-file-for-an-installed-application.html