# How can I get the click version from inside my app

Tags: ubuntu-touch, click-packages

Is there a way I can get my app version (i.e. the "version" field in manifest.json) from inside the app? I'd like to avoid generating a file that contains the version string.

Comment: You may prepare it easily with a bash script and the file manager app. See:http://askubuntu.com/questions/784372/how-can-i-make-a-click-file-from-an-installed-app/784374#784374